# Cannot print the final data in a line

Tags: java, text, text-files

I have a question here.I need to open a text file and the print the output according the the pattern i want.I used regex pattern method to get the desired pattern.I wan remove the curly braces,commas and brackets.I managed to do so but i dont know why my code doesn't print out the last line..

The data in text file would be like this

```
[{8}    ,    {11}    ,    {19}   ,    {21}     ,     {34,
20,
33,
26,
17,
35,
36,
49,
4,
48,
39,
1,
10,
41,
14,
9,
7,
16,
46,
45,
29,
3,
44,
43,
38,
37,
13,
22,
23,
47,
25,
40,
2,
5,
15,
18,
30,
28,
42,
50,
12,
32,
24,
6,
31,
27}]
```

My Code As Follows

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.FileReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;


public class ClusterLine {
private static File f;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {



    String sentence = "";
    try {


        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        sentence = br.readLine();





       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);
        while (m.find()) {

           System.out.println(m.group(0).replace(",", "").replaceAll("\\{", "").replaceAll("\\}", ""));
        }
```

I should get output like this if use above code

```
8

11

19

21

34 20 33 26 17 35 36 49 4 48 39 1 10 41 14 7 16 46
```

But my question here is why I cannot get the output like above?The final line is missing.I could only get output like this.

```
8

11

19

21
```

is there any wrong with the method i used? Hope someone could help me..Tq

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it readable.

Comment: ok..i edit it ready ..:)

Comment: No, your data is still unreadable. Indent it, too.

Comment: sorry..i will edit again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using pattern matching.

Here the solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String newString = "[{124}, {126}, {12, 14}, {13, 18, 130, 113}]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(newString);
    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1).replace(",", ""));
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
124
126
12 14
13 18 130 113
```

---

**ADDED**

For me code below return as expected:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String newString = "[{8} , {11} , {19} , {21} , {34, 20, 33, 26, 17, 35, 36, 49, 4, 48, 39, 1, 10, 41, 14, 9, 7, 16, 46, 45, 29, 3, 44, 43, 38, 37, 13, 22, 23, 47, 25, 40, 2, 5, 15, 18, 30, 28, 42, 50, 12, 32, 24, 6, 31, 27}]";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(newString);
        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.group(1).replace(",", ""));
        }
}
```

The output will be:

```
8
11
19
21
34 20 33 26 17 35 36 49 4 48 39 1 10 41 14 9 7 16 46 45 29 3 44 43 38 37 13 22 23 47 25 40 2 5 15 18 30 28 42 50 12 32 24 6 31 27
```

You should check the variable:

```
sentence = br.readLine();
```

---

**ADDED 2**

You have line breaks in your file. So you should remove this from your string:

```
newString = newString.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(newString);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1).replace(",", " "));
}
```

Comment: i will pass the getCLuster() method to the string and then try to do like yours.thx alot..

Comment: If it's the right solution. Please mark it as the right answer please.

Comment: yes..pattern matching was the correct way to do it..tq

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

1. Split on `,`. So you will get an aray.
2. On each element of array remove curly braces.
3. Run loop.

And have the following pseudo code in the loop:

```
bw.write(arra[i]);
bw.newLine();
```